# Segmentation fault while using SDL

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sdl

[SOLVED]I'm following [this tutorial (video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55AKZx1TByw&list=PL949B30C9A609DEE8) and I'm at this very moment. I had no problems with compiling, but when it comes to running the program it's just flashing for a second and turning off. So I've run the debugger and I found a segmentation fault from `SDL_DisplayFormat` in my `load_image` function, when I comment off lines where I load images it works ok, but I can't find the reason of the problem.

[SOLUTION] I haven't fill the .bmp files that is why the SDL_DisplayFormat didn't work. Once filed with drawning, everything started to work.

Here is my code:

```
#include "game.h"
/*TODO 
*stworzyć plik z blokami "blocks.bmp"
*stworzyć plik  z tlem "background.bmp"
*uzywac jako tla do obrazkow 000,255,255
*
*/
game::game()
{
    //zaladowanie ekranu
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGTH, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    //ladowanei obrazkow

    //ustawianie polozenia i rozmiaru kamery
    camera.x = camera.y = 0;
    camera.w = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    camera.h = SCREEN_HEIGTH;
    //inicjalizacja kierunku w kotrym sie poruszamy
    direction[0] = direction[1] = 0;
    running = true;
    block = (load_image("blocks.bmp"));
    background = (load_image("background.bmp"));
}
game::~game()
{
    SDL_FreeSurface(block);
    SDL_FreeSurface(background);
    SDL_Quit();
}
SDL_Surface* game::load_image (const char* filename)
{
    SDL_Surface* tmp = SDL_LoadBMP(filename);
    SDL_Surface* tmp2 = SDL_DisplayFormat(tmp);
    //do odkomentowania kolorkey na razie zeby sprawdzac kolizje
    //  SDL_SetColorKey(tmp2, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff)
    SDL_FreeSurface(tmp);
    return tmp2;
}
void game::handleEvents()
{
    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                running = false;
                return;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_LEFT:
                        direction[0] = 1;
                        break;
                    case SDLK_RIGHT:
                        direction[1] = 1;
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case SDL_KEYUP:
                switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_LEFT:
                        direction[0] = 0;
                        break;
                    case SDLK_RIGHT:
                        direction[1] = 0;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
void game::start()
{
    while(1)
    {
        handleEvents();
        SDL_Flip(screen);
    }
}
```

Comment: Throwing it out there: `std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface> tmp(SDL_LoadBMP(filename), SDL_FreeSurface);`

Answer (score 2):

One advise up front: Provide complete, minimal code including compile instructions. Yours doesn't have a main() function and the class definition is missing too (game.h). After reconstructing this and running it in a debugger, I find that the first SDL_LoadBMP() returns NULL (maybe that's the same at yours, but here it's definitely the case that I don't have the according files), so I have no clue if you have the same problem or not.

Now, what you can try to fix this is to check returnvalues. In this case, try this:

```
SDL_Surface* tmp = SDL_LoadBMP(filename);
if(!tmp)
    throw std::runtime_error("SDL_LoadBMP() failed");
```

Using a unique_ptr or some custom wrapper class is also a good advice in order to not leak resources.

Comment: All right, the problem was that the .bmp files was empty, once I've put somthing into them it started to work.
Thanks for the tips, I'll follow them from now on